# Find the area of the top half of the polar curve $r=3-2 \cos \theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, curves

Find the area of the top half of the polar curve : 
$$r=3-2\cos \theta$$

I'm not sure how to tackle this. I need to find the area of a unique shape (almost a semi-circle), but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start with $ A= \frac12\int r^2 d \theta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw tha graph of the cartesian equation $y=3-2\cos x$. With this, it is easy to draw (without the need of a computer) the graph in polar coordinates of $r=3-2\cos \theta$, it would look something like that :

[image]

Now notice that the top of the figure is obtained when $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$. So, the area is given by
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi r^2 d\theta = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi (3-2\cos \theta)^2 d\theta$$

Comment: That makes so much sense now! I will do that, thank you.